# Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header value 'text' in response does not match any of sent values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, websocket, pelco

I have a React project and I am streaming a live video through websocket, but when they update the camera firmware I get an error on websocket connection.

This is how I create the WebSocket,

```
 wsRef.current = new WebSocket(`ws://${ip}:${80}/websocket`, ["tv-img-protocol",]);
```

On some specific camera firmwares, I can create the WebSocket connection easily but on some firmwares I get this error message on the Network tab and I cannot create the WebSocket connection,

> **Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header value 'text' in response does not match any of sent values**

I am new to these topics so I couldn't understand the cause of this problem. When I searched online I found this:
**The new firmware might support different subprotocols for communication, and it's sending "text" as the preferred subprotocol in the handshake response.** Does this mean I should get in touch with the camera providers and ask them to change the handshake response or is there anything I can do with my code.

Here is the whole code to create the websocket connection:

```
 const wsRef = useRef<WebSocket | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    wsRef.current = new WebSocket(`ws://${ip}:${80}/websocket`, [
      "tv-img-protocol",
    ]);
    wsRef.current.onopen = () => setIsLoading(false);
    wsRef.current.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    wsRef.current.onmessage = function (event: MessageEvent) {
      let buffer: ArrayBuffer[] = [];
      let ai = 0;
      let ak;
      let ap = 0;
      let ag = 0;
      let ctr = 0;

      if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        if (event.data.byteLength !== 16000) {
          ak = new Uint8Array(ap + event.data.byteLength);

          for (let i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
            ak.set(new Uint8Array(buffer[i]), ag);
            ag += 16000;
          }

          ak.set(new Uint8Array(event.data), ag);
          let now = event.timeStamp;
          if (imgRef.current && now >= lastTimeRef.current) {
            lastTimeRef.current = now;
            imgRef.current.src = "data:image/png;base64," + bytesToBase64(ak);
          } else {
            console.log("Timing Error on camera stream.");
          }
          buffer = [];
          ap = 0;
          ai = 0;
          ag = 0;
          ak = "";
        } else {
          buffer[ai] = event.data;
          ap += event.data.byteLength;
          ai++;
        }
      }
    };
    return () => {
      wsRef.current?.close();
    };
  }, [ip]);
```

Comment: The error means the server supports other subprotocol "text", the server is supposed to reply with "tv-img-protocol" if they do support it. Yes, you should consult with the camera provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my code and now I can create WebSocket connection:

```
wsRef.current = new WebSocket(`ws://${ip}:${80}/websocket`, ["binary"]);
wsRef.current.onopen = () => {
setIsLoading(false);
wsRef.current.send("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: tv-img-protocol\r\n\r\n");
};
```